# How to cut video between seconds with FFmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, trim

For example :

```
startMs = 2.4.   
endMs = 5.4  
I have tried this code:  
String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-ss", "" + startMs, "-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec", "copy", "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs), dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

But the cutting process happens with Full values (int values)... from "sec 2" to "sec 5"
Is there any way to cut video with "float values" ?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the timestamp? Something like:

```
String startMs = "00:00:02.400";
String endMs  = "00:00:05.400";
Srting totalMs = "00:00:03.000";

String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-ss", "" + startMs, "-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec", "copy", "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs), dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

[Refer to this link](https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg)

You may need to adapt something and I can't test it now, but it's woth a try. Good luck!